# Force terminate a WPF application

Tags: wpf, terminate

I need to terminate a running WPF application (e.g. wpf.exe). This app however did override the OnClosing event by doing the following

```
protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
{      
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

I tried to do "taskkill /f /im wpf.exe" but it still doesn't terminate it. How can I force terminate this app?

Comment: good ol' task manager.

Comment: thanks for your reply. The app is occupying the entire screen (it doesn't minimize either) so I can't go to the task manager. I have an ahk configured so a key-combination should kill this app

Answer (score 1):

rather than doing it

```
    protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
{      
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

try

```
void Window_Closing(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    IClosing context = DataContext as IClosing;
    if (context != null)
    {
        e.Cancel = !context.OnClosing();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for not being very clear but I don't have a control over this app. I've seen the code but I cannot modify it